# Azure sql Data warehouse maximums

Tags: azure, azure-sql-database

I have recently started exploring Azure Sql Datawarehouse . However I am not able to find the below database maximum parameters anywhere in the documentations .

**Parameters**

```
Columns       Maximum per table or view 
Names         Maximum length of database and column names
Characters    Maximum number of characters in a char/varchar field
Connections   Maximum connections to the server
concurency    Maximm number of concurrent users
Row size      Maximum row size
DISTRIBUTION KEY       Maximum per table
Index         Maximum per table
Cluster size  Maximum cluster size(in terms of compressed datasize)
```

Comment: A simple Google search led me to this: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/sql-data-warehouse/sql-data-warehouse-service-capacity-limits

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You will find capacity limits on [this](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/sql-data-warehouse/sql-data-warehouse-service-capacity-limits) official documentation.

Hope this helps.